# Array creation and printing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a whole bunch of `divs` that have a class called `ofint`. Each of them may have additional classes. I'd like to store this information about each div and then print them.

So I'm trying to loop through all divs of class `ofint` and store the `div id` and its `classes` in an array. The idea is that I'll search the array later, but for now I need to create it and make sure it's storing the right information.

I have some idea how to get there, but can't quite do it. How do I complete this and then print the array for double checking purposes?

```
var myarr = new array;  
$(".ofint").each(function(){
    //store the div id and div classes in the array
    myarr[this.id][classes] = //the list of classes;
});
//print the array here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like this:

```
var myarr = [];
$(".ofint").each(function(){
    myarr.push({ id: this.id, classes: this.className.split(" ") });
});
```

You could do a print of the output to the body, for example:

```
$.each(myarr, function() {
  $(document.body).append("ID:<b>"+this.id+"</b> - " + 
                          this.classes.join(', ') + "<br />");
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KHd6J/), in this case we're storing an array of objects with 2 properties, the `id` and an array of classes, the output is just looping through and dumping these 2 properties to the page.

Comment: Works exactly the way I needed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Nick Craver has already given you a solution, but I'm just posting this to point out some errors in your original code:

1. JavaScript is case-sensitive: it's `Array`, not `array`. The shorthand notation `[]` is also equivalent.
2. You're trying to use `myarr` as a two-dimensional array, i.e. `myarr[this.id][classes]`: first, you need to initialize the inner array just like the outer one, and second, `classes` should be a string because you want to store it under that exact name.

So your original code should look something like this:

```
var myarr = [];
// OR
var myarr = new Array();

$('.ofint').each(function() {
  myarr[this.id] = []; // creating the inner array here

  myarr[this.id]['classes'] = /* list of classes */;
  // OR
  myarr[this.id].classes = /* list of classes */;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As I have answered before in SO, if you are using Mozilla Firefox, `alert(myarr.toSource())` should be sufficient for simple debugging purpose. You can also do `$('#debugconsole').text(myarr.toSource())` if you already have a div for printing debug values.

Otherwise consider installing Firebug as it comes with many more debugging facilities (like tweaking your HTML elements on the spot to see the changes)

Comment: Great tip. Makes debugging so easy. +1

Answer (score 2):

i highly recommend to install firebug, a firefox addon. with that installed and its console activated you then can do console.log(myarr);

within the console you can simply click on that just generated output and analyze the array.

in my opinion ther is no js development without firebug =)

for your approach this should work fine:

```
$('.ofint').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

or

```
$('.ofint').each(function() {
    $("body").append($(this).attr("class")+"<br />");
});
```

if you just want to put out to the body

but you also can just analyze the manipulated html via firebug aswell.